# Cannot read property 'every' of undefined in Angular 2 Test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm writing a test for my component. I'm having following error.

```
Cannot read property 'every' of undefined
```

In my .ts, I used 'every' as below:

```
constructor(
    private store: Store<any>,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
  ) {
    const assetStore$ = this.store.select('cmsAsset');
    // Filter is a dirty hack to remove bad entities left in place by 'Create'
    this.cmsAssetEntities$ = assetStore$.let(reducers.getCmsAssets)
      .filter(assets => assets.every(asset => Object.keys(asset).length > 0));
  }
```

I have no idea what to do in .spec file to resolve the error. Please advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
.filter(assets => assets && assets.every(asset => Object.keys(asset).length > 0));
```